# Vuetify/Javascript why am I getting a ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working in Vuetify and I am trying to use a javascript client for Prometheus in order to get some data into my application. The page is [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prometheus-query) from what I can tell I followed their example, but I keep getting a ReferenceError: Prometheus is not defined when I try to run this. my code is here:

```
<script>
import 'prometheus-query'

 const prom = new PrometheusDriver({'removed for security'
 }
 })
 const q = 'count(node_uname_info{job="MAK_Eos_Lab"})'
 prom.instantQuery(q)
   .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.result)
 })
.catch(console.error)

export default {
 name: 'Mackinac',
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import it before using it :

```
 import { PrometheusDriver } from 'prometheus-query';
```

then use it :

```
 const prom = new PrometheusDriver(...)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Why didnt my "import 'prometheus-query' " work?

Comment: you're welcome, `import 'prometheus-query'` doesn't expose the `PrometheusDriver` object